# can't solve next-head-count is missing error

Tags: next.js

I know this is a duplicate, but I couldn't solve my problem with those answers. so here is my code:

```
//_document.tsx
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head />
        <body dir="rtl">
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}


//_app.tsx
import "../styles/globals.scss";
import Head from "next/head";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <title>Bitbarg</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Descriptions" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <body dir="rtl" />
      </Head>

      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </>
  );
}
export default MyApp;
```

I'm still getting this error.
I tried taking all _app.tsx `Head` tag in _document.tsx, this removed the error but I'm getting new error as:

> Titles should be defined at the page-level using next/head.

I tried only putting code bellow in _app.tsx, but it gives me the next-head-count error again.

```
<Head>
   <title>Bitbarg</title>     
</Head>
```

Comment: Remove `<body dir="rtl" />` from `<Head>` in your `_app.tsx`. That's not a valid element to have inside `head`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are encountering the error because you are trying to use the `Head` component both in the `_document.tsx` and `_app.tsx` files, which is causing conflicts in rendering the page-level metadata. The `Head` component should only be used in the individual page components, not in both `_document.tsx` and `_app.tsx`.

To fix this issue, follow these steps:

1. Remove the `Head` component from the `_app.tsx` file entirely, including the `title`, `meta`, and `link` tags.
2. Keep the `Head` component in the `_document.tsx` file to define any common metadata that should be present on all pages. For example, you can set the `title`, `description`, and `favicon` here. But make sure you remove any conflicting metadata that might be duplicated from `_app.tsx`.

Your updated `_document.tsx` should look like this:

```
//_document.tsx
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from "next/document";

export default class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          {/* Define common metadata here */}
          <title>Bitbarg</title>
          <meta name="description" content="Descriptions" />
          <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        </Head>
        <body dir="rtl">
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    );
  }
}
```

By following these steps, you should be able to resolve the "next-head-count is missing" error and define your page-level metadata correctly. Remember that individual page components can still use the `Head` component to set specific metadata unique to each page.  from _app.js as I was using it already in _document.js